# Types of constructors in classes

Tags: c++, class

I am writing a class for college and I have a problem with constructors..

I have to create a class to calculate P and V of a cylinder. I need functions set(), to set the values, get H, get R to get values and P and V to calculate the P and V. I also need 3 constructors, first one to ask the user to enter the values for R and H, second one to set them to 10 and 5.5 and third one to initialize them to 3 and 1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Cilindar{
    public:
        Cilindar();
        Cilindar(float R, float H);
        float getH();
        float getR();
        void set();
        float Plostina(float R, float H);
        float Volumen(float R, float H);
    private:
        float radius;
        float visina;
};

void Cilindar::set(){
    cout << "Vnesi go radiusot" << endl;
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "Vnesi ja visinata" << endl;
    cin >> visina;
}

float Cilindar::getH(){
    return visina;
}

float Cilindar::getR(){
    return radius;
}

float Cilindar::Plostina(float R, float H){
    return 2 * R * 3.14 * (R + H);
}

float Cilindar::Volumen(float R, float H){
    return R * R * 3.14 * H;
}

Cilindar::Cilindar(){
    set();
    cout << "Plostinata iznesuva: " << Plostina(radius, visina) << endl;
    cout << "Volumenot iznesuva: " << Volumen(radius, visina) << endl;
}

Cilindar::Cilindar(float R, float H){
    cout << "Plostinata iznesuva: " << Plostina(R, H) << endl;
    cout << "Volumenot iznesuva: " << Volumen(R, H) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Cilindar c1, c2(10, 5.5), c3;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far, I made the first constructor to ask the user, second one with 10 and 5.5 but third one I don't know how can I initialize the values to the constructor, because a constructor with 2 arguments already exists, so what is another way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want the third constructor to do?

Comment: Why does `Volumen` for example take any arguments? Why not `float Cilindar::Volumen(void) { return radius * radius * 3.1415926535897932f * visina; }` so you can go for `c2.Volumen()` instead of `c2.Volumen(c2.getR(), c2.getH())`? Your `Plostina` and `Volumen` methods are members but don't actually make use of the fact that they got access to the data members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the constructor with 2 arguments again (with different parameters).

```
Cilindar c1, c2(10, 5.5), c3(3, 1);
```

There is no need for another constructor.

Good luck.